# how to get a specific id within 5 rows in a paging query in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function in php I use it for paging it is like this :

```
$query = "SELECT id, 
      FROM table
      ORDER BY id ASC
      LIMIT $offset,5";
```

this work fine but what I want is to get the page that contain id number let say 10 and with it the other 4 rows, I want it to return something like this:

- 7,8,9,10,11,12 -> if I give it id number 10.
- 25,26,27,28,29 -> if I give it id number 26 and so on.

like it would return the 5 rows but I want to know how to set the offset that will get me 
the page that have the 5 rows with the specified id included.

what should I do like adding where clause or something to get what I want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the IDs in your table won't be consecutive if you delete some rows. The code below should work in such conditions:

```
$result = mysql_query('select count(*) from table where id < ' . $someId);
$offset = mysql_result($result, 0, 0);

$result = mysql_query('select * from table order by id limit ' . max($offset - 2, 0) . ',5');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
//but for pagination to work $page should be $page*$limit, so new rows will come to your page

$limit = 5;
$start = ($page*limit) -2;  // for normal pagination
$start = $page -2; // for your case, if you want ids around the $page value - in this case for id = 10 you will get 8 9 10 11 12
if ($start < 0) $start = 0; // for first page not to try and get negative values

$query = "SELECT id, 
          FROM rowa
          ORDER BY id ASC
          LIMIT $start,$limit";
```

Comment: Yeah I know that that is not my problem I edit it above to make clearer. Thanks

Comment: edited -replace - $start = ($page*limit) -2;  with $start = $page-2; for your case, getting rows near the $page given